# python regular expression "\1"

Tags: python, regex

Can anyone tell me what does "\1" mean in the following regular expression in Python?

```
re.sub(r'(\b[a-z]+) \1', r'\1', 'cat in the the hat')
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`\1` is equivalent to `re.search(...).group(1)`, the first parentheses-delimited expression inside of the regex.

It's also, fun fact, part of the reason that regular expressions are significantly slower in Python and other programming languages than [required to be by CS theory](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html).

Answer (score 25):

The first `\1` means the first group - i.e. the first bracketed expression `(\b[a-z]+)`

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) `\number`

"Matches the contents of the group of the same number. Groups are numbered starting from 1. For example, (.+) \1 matches 'the the' or '55 55', but not 'thethe' (note the space after the group)"

In your case it is looking for a repeated "word" (well, block of lower case letters).

The second `\1` is the replacement  to use in case of a match, so a repeated word will be replaced by a single word.

Answer (score 16):

`\1` is a backreference.
It matches, what ever matched in your brackets, in this case `the`

You are basically saying

- match empty string at the beginning of a word (\b)
- match alphabetical characters from a-z, one or more times
- match the term in brackets again

cat in *(' ''the')' the'* hat

Answer (score 4):

**Example**

The following code using Python regex to find the repeating digits in given string

```
import re

result = re.search(r'(\d)\1{3}','54222267890' )
print result.group()
```

This gives the output:

```
2222
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [python docs for the re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> `\number`
>
> Matches the contents of the group of the same number. Groups are
>   numbered starting from 1. For example, `(.+) \1` matches `'the the'` or
>   `'55 55'`, but not `'thethe'` (note the space after the group). This
>   special sequence can only be used to match one of the first 99 groups.
>   If the first digit of number is 0, or number is 3 octal digits long,
>   it will not be interpreted as a group match, but as the character with
>   octal value number. Inside the `'['` and `']'` of a character class, all
>   numeric escapes are treated as characters.

Your example is basically the same as what is explained in the docs.

Answer (score -1):

r'(\b[a-z]+ \1', '\1', 'cat in the the hat')

| word | next-word | IsMatched() | replace with word |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cat | in | No | NA |
| in | the | No | NA |
| the | the | Yes | the |
| the | hat | No | NA |

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).