# pandas replacing by function output (Applying a function to rows based on regex)

Tags: python, pandas

Basically I have a dataframe that could look like this:

```
ID NAME                      PAINT
0  some_name:target          blue
1  some_other_name           pink
2  other_name: other_target  yellow
3  other_name                black
```

And only want to replace values that follow a certain regex by applying a function to them.

```
def f(x):
  name, target = x.split(":")
  return "[" + target + "]" + " " + name
```

```
ID NAME                        PAINT
0  [target] some_name          blue
1  some_other_name             pink
2  [other_target] other_name   yellow
3  other_name                  black
```

I imagine it would look something like this but whatever works

```
df.replace(to_replace=strings_found_by_regex, value=f(strings_found_by_regex))
```

This could probably be done by iterating over rows and seing if those cells match the regex and then appplying `f(x)` but that looks rather ugly and I wondered whether there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, using [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Find out regex explanation here,
[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VPnTvY/1)

```
df.NAME.str.replace("(.+)\s*:\s*(.+)", r"[\2] \1")
```

---

```
0           [target] some_name
1              some_other_name
2    [other_target] other_name
3                   other_name
Name: NAME, dtype: object
```

Comment: Shouldn't \2 be stripped?  Row index 2 NAME column desired answer  is `[other_target] other_name` while this answer provides `[ other_target]  other_name` (i.e. extra space in `[ other_target]`.

Comment: care to explain the raw string part? Thanks!

Comment: @MatejNovosad, update regex link with substitution & here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20802242/4985099) to thread that discuss about backreference

Comment: @MatejNovosad Here is another interesting [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20802056/4985099) that explains what "\1" does.. Hope it clarifies your queries.