# How to average DataFrame row with another row only if the first row is a substring of other next row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, wildcard, matching

I have a dataframe called 'data':

```
USER    VALUE
XOXO      21
ABC-1      2
ABC-1B     4
ABC-2      4
ABC-2B     6
PEPE      12
```

I want to combine 'ABC-1' with 'ABC-1B' into a single row using the first USER name and then averaging the two values to arrive here:

```
USER    VALUE
XOXO      21
ABC-1      3
ABC-2      5
PEPE      12
```

The dataframe may not be in order and there are other values in there as well that are unrelated that don't need averaging. I only want to average the two rows where 'XXX-X' is in 'XXX-XB'

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'USER':['XOXO','ABC-1','ABC-1B','ABC-2','ABC-2B', 'PEPE'], 'VALUE':[21,2,4,4,6,12]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try,

```
df.USER = df.USER.str.replace('(-\d)B', r"\1")
df = df.groupby("USER", as_index=False, sort=False).VALUE.mean()

print(df)
```

---

```
    USER  VALUE
0   XOXO     21
1  ABC-1      3
2  ABC-2      5
3   PEPE     12
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what is going on inside the replace? I've never seen that stuff in the parameters before

Comment: @stackoverflow ``\1 is equivalent to re.search(...).group(1)``, so ``(-\d)B`` would match ``-1B`` replace with just `-1` first group value.

Comment: also, running this doesn't average/combine the rows:

`data = pd.DataFrame({'USER':['XOXO','ABC-1','ABC-1B','ABC-2','ABC-2B', 'PEPE'], 'VALUE':[21,2,4,4,6,12]})
data.USER = data.USER.str.replace('(-\d)B', r"\1")
data.groupby("USER", as_index=False, sort=False).VALUE.mean()
print(data)`

It does however change the names to be the same @sushanth

Comment: @stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802056/python-regular-expression-1/20802242

Comment: i should have included another column in the example @sushanth

how would we preserve any other columns that aren't being used in the dataframe? as of now the code will only keep USER and VALUE but nothing else like VALUE2 for instance

`data = pd.DataFrame({'USER':['XOXO','ABC-1','ABC-1B','ABC-2','ABC-2B', 'PEPE'], 'VALUE':[21,2,4,4,6,12], 'VALUE2':['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE', 'FFF']})`

Comment: @stackoverflow, its would be better if you could post as a new question instead of extending this question.