# Can someone explain \\1 in a regular expression sub expression

Tags: python, python-3.10

For the below:

`text = re.sub('([\]\".:?!-])\n','\\1</p>\n<p>',text)`

Could you please explain to me what does the \1 does?

Comment: this is a backreference to the capturing group

Comment: Your question's already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802056/python-regular-expression-1)